# style id - colorful swirls

Tags: style-identification

[image]

I am trying to find the name or designation of this type of graphic. Is there a certain name for this style or type? I want to create something similar but am having a hard time finding more examples.

Comment: Well... [**Oil Color Swirl**](https://www.google.com/search?hl=en&site=imghp&tbm=isch&source=hp&biw=1176&bih=1320&q=oil+and+water+colors&oq=oil+and+water+colors&gs_l=img.3..0i8i30l2j0i10i24.659.3396.0.3549.20.16.0.3.3.0.284.2065.0j9j3.12.0....0...1ac.1.64.img..6.14.1792.gaMS7e2QGjo#hl=en&tbm=isch&q=oil+color+swirl) has your image as the second result.

Answer (score 0):

This effect in the image posted is about water color effect.

This effect can be brought about by a mixture of Pantone Colors.

The colors used will be CMYK and RGB depending upon the quality of printing and material of printing.

Comment: Hello Design Info. Please do not link to your own website unless you directly link to a relevant article that is part of your answer to the question. The community is very unforgiving about non-relevant self-promotion. If you do link to your own site, give full disclosure and state that you are the owner of the site linked to.

Answer (score 0):

As Scott indicated in the comments, the term 'Oil Color Swirl' seem to describe your image pretty well.